# Evitar Duplicados en una Lista c#

Tags: c#

Hola como puedo hacer para Identificar un código que ya existe en una Lista en c#, ahorita lo estaba haciendo de esta forma y lo detecta pero quisiera aumentar la cantidad en lugar de retornar.

Mi código es:

```
 foreach (EN_Producto producto in ((BindingSource)gridView1.DataSource).List)
 {
    if (Valor.ToUpper() == producto.Id_Pro.Trim().ToUpper())
    //producto.Cantidad = +1;

    return;
 }
```

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Si te estoy entendiendo bien, podrías usar un Dictionary y preguntar si ese código existe, y de ser el caso, le sumas 1, en caso no exista, lo agregas con el valor de 1.

Comment: Gracias por editar tu pregunta Emin! , saludos!

Comment: creo que no me estoy explicando bien :( pero lo que deseo hacer es que si un elemento esta repetido entonces

Sumarle 1 en la columna cantidad

Codigo=0003 Cantitidad=1

si Codigo 0003 ya existe entonces Cantidad=1+1=2

ayuda por favor :(

Comment: Intente de la forma que me indican pero me da error.

Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado suprimido
Error CS1934 No se encontró ninguna implementación del patrón de consulta para el tipo de origen 'IList'. No se encontró 'Where'. Puede especificar de forma explícita el tipo de la variable de rango 'p'. SOFT_VENTAS C:\Users\hmeurbinad\Desktop\12-Mayo-2021\30 Marzo 2021\Sistema\Sln_MicrosellLite Sql\Microsell_Lite\Cotizacion\Frm_Cotizacion.cs 854 Activo

Comment: gracias me a funcionado perfecto les agradezco por haberse tomado de su valioso tiempo en ayudarme.

Comment: @EminUrbina, si las respuestas dadas te fueron utiles dales un voto positivo, y a la q te ayudo a resolver tu problema marcala como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar **Linq** para saber si ese elemento existe

```
var contador =(from p in ((BindingSource)gridView1.DataSource).List                             
               where Valor.Trim().ToUpper() == p.Id_Pro.Trim().ToUpper()
               select p).Count();
```

Aqui se hace una consulta **Linq** que va a devolver la cantidad de elementos de tu coleccion que cumplan con la condicion puesta en el **where**, para devolver el total se utiliza el metodo **Count**

Una vez q tengas la cantidad de elementos que se repiten puedes hacer esto :

```
if(contador > 0)
{
   var producto =  (from p in ((BindingSource)gridView1.DataSource).List
                    where Valor.Trim().ToUpper() == p.Id_Pro.Trim().ToUpper()
                    select p).FirstOrDefault();

   producto.Cantidad += 1;
}
else
{
   //Añadir producto
}
```

Preguntas si el contador es mayor que cero, de ser mayor que cero quiere decir que ese elemento existe, por tanto haces otra consulta **Linq** donde vas a obtener ese producto y actualizar su cantidad aumentándole 1, en caso de no existir se añade el producto a tu lista

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los usings

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: a entiendo, bueno y en el caso de que quiera aumentar a la cantidad es decir 

si el codigo="003" existe entonces le aumento a la  Cantidad+=1 del Codigo="003";

como hago eso disculpa la molestia.

Comment: @EminUrbina, imagino que una vez q guardes la cantidad, debes borrar los productos que se repiten y dejar solamente uno?

Comment: no colega no deseo eliminarlo lo que deseo hacer es aumentar la cantidad, es decir si escaneo un codigo de un producto una vez lo agrego, y cantidad es 1, ahora si vuelvo a escanear el mismo codigo del producto no lo agrego solo actualizo la cantidad a 2 y asi sucesivamente.

Comment: @EminUrbina, revisa lo nuevo que puse

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener una lista de los elementos no duplicados lo puedes realizar de la siguiente forma, donde se agrupara la lista de acuerdo a la propiedad `Id_Pro` de tu objeto `producto` agregando únicamente el primero de cada elemento repetido en la lista original.

```
var listaFinal = ((BindingSource)gridView1.DataSource).List.GroupBy(x => x.Id_Pro).Select (x => x.First ()).ToList();
```